# How can I alter a DBIx::Class object value without updating the actual DB

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I am checking for mismatch usernames in one of my applications.
If it finds a mismatch username, I wrap the value in `<mark>` tags.

I want to update my DBIx::Class object's username value before passing it back to my JS.

I currently have the below, which is almost what I want but not quite.

```
my $mismatch_username = check_for_mismatch_username($self, $id, 'AD');
    if(defined $mismatch_username)
    {
      my $flagged_username = "<mark>".$info->accountname."</mark> <font color=\"red\">(Mismatch: $mismatch_username)</font>";
       $info->update({accountname => $flagged_username});
    }
$info = {$info->get_columns};
$self->render(json => {info => $info});
```

It is very important I don't update the DB value. I only want to update the variable's value. I am currently still looking through the DBIx::Class documentation.

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Seeing DBIC code and HTML with a font tag in one program is... Unusual.

Comment: It seemed easier in my mind to add the tags before sending it back through JSON, instead of sending the information back and having yet another ajax call to figure out if there is a mismatch and adding the font tags in my js. is there an easier way I missed?

Comment: It's called CSS. Your JSON should have a flag as meta data, and your frontend should mark the content based on that, which in turn would use CSS to change the color. `<font>` tags are only about <strike>10 years</strike> 17 (damn, I'm old) out of date. They were deprecated with [HTML 4.01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#HTML_versions_timeline). I meant my comment as a joke, because we typically see this kind of HTML with CGI applications, and people writing CGI have never heard of DBIC. If this stuff works for you, that's fine. But there are more modern approaches.

Comment: I knew there had to be another approach, being that the above breaks the separation of interests that following the MVC model helps you obtain. I'll definitely be looking to correct this shortly. Even though it was supposed to be a joke, I appreciate the information so I can correct it ......-_-. Thanks.

Comment: This is probably lost in translation, but it's called "separation of _concerns_". In case you google it, or something. Are you using an MVC framework? It's btw totally legit to return an HTML, but then it's not really JSON any more. It's more like an asynchronous call that returns `text/html`. But the `<font>` tag is still horrible. I'd go with `<span class="epic-fail">...</span>` or whatever. Just not `<font>`.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I am currently using Mojolicious because I am required to use perl. I learned MVC concepts using .NET. Which I still use time to time when I'm able.

Comment: Mojo is very modern, and combining it with DBIC is fun. Web MVC is of course a bit different than a classic SDI or MDI application. I just sometimes feel that the model part is somewhat underrepresented in Mojo, but then I have a strong Catalyst background. If you would like to get some feedback on your code, feel free to post a larger chunk on the code review SE and give me  a shout.

Comment: I felt the same way when I first started and only ventured away from catalyst due to the complex setup ..... I will definitely post some code for review. Very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify the object if you don't want it to be modified.

(You could, of course, update the field without saving it using `$info->accountname(…)`. But that would still leave the object in a modified state, where other code could potentially save it. It'd also potentially fail if the HTML markup was rejected by a validator on the field.)

If all you actually need is to change the username in the JSON, generate the data that'll go into the JSON first, then update the appropriate field in the data before rendering it:

```
my $data = { $info->get_columns };
if (defined $mismatch_username) {
    $data->{accountname} = "<mark>…";
}
$self->render(json => { info => $data });
```